# Stata -- extract regression output for 3500 regressions run in a loop

Tags: for-loop, output, regression, stata

I am using a `forval` loop to run 3,500 regressions, one for each group.  I then need to summarize the results.  Typically, when I use loops to run regressions I use the estimates store function followed by `estout`.  Below is a sample code.  But I believe there is a limit of 300 that this code can handle.  I would very much appreciate if someone could let me know how to automate the process for 3,500 regressions.

Sample code:

```
forval j = 1/3500 {

    regress y x if group == `j'
    estimates store m`j', title(Model `j')
}

estout m* using "Results.csv", cells(b t)   ///
   legend label varlabels(_cons constant)   ///
       stats(r2 df_r N, fmt(3 0 1) label(R-sqr dfres N)) replace
```

Comment: Nick and others, I have not been able to get statsby to work.  Would appreciate an example showing how to extract the results.  Thanks!

Comment: It's the other way round: this site is focused on posters asking for specific advice on specific code. Show us what didn't work.

Comment: I tried something like this: statsby _b _se, by (group) saving(my_reg): regress ret2 ret2_lag.  But then I am not sure what to do after that.  How can I see the results?  I have searched the web but can't find any example.  I know fewer people use Stata today but then this seems like such a standard issue.

Comment: ... and in what sense didn't that work?

Comment: I changed the code to: statsby _b _se, by (group) saving($path\my_reg.dta): regress ret2 ret2_lag.  Seems to be working.  Thanks, Nick.  If I run into issues as I implement this fully, will write back.  Reps to you.

Comment: 3500 regressions might not be instant.

Comment: Yeah, I am testing right now with a few groups.  Once I get what I need, I will implement for the 3,500.

Comment: You can also use `byvar`: http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s392602.html

Comment: You guys are absolutely amazing!  I am very thankful to you both for taking the time to respond to my question.  Your generosity has saved me so much time and I am very grateful for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `statsby` where I run a regression of price on mpg for each of the 5 groups defined by the rep78 variable and store the results in Stata dataset called my_regs:

```
sysuse auto, clear
statsby _b _se, by(rep78) saving(my_regs): reg price mpg
use my_regs.dta
```

If you prefer, you can omit the `saving()` option and then your dataset will be replaced in memory by the regression results, so you won't need to open the file directly with `use`.